# Time based for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a program which includes execution of time based while loop. Some thing like..

```
import time
endtime=time.time()+60.0 #1minute
while (time.time()<endtime):
    do something
```

I was just wondering if this is possible using for loop? Can I build a time based for loop in python?

Comment: `for i in xrange(1000000): if (time.time()<endtime):`, It won't be as robust as the `while` loop but it is a kind of workaround.

Comment: What loop values do you want the `for` loop to iterate over? Whatever you want, you can build an iterator for it, but you have to know what you want.

Comment: @abarnert: I dont want any exact number. I just want it to work for a particular amount of time.

Comment: Why not just nest your for loop work inside the timed while loop? I still don't understand what your use case is.

Comment: @BhoomikaSheth: Then what's wrong with what you already have? The only reason a `for` loop would be better is if you needed some value each time through the loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

From https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

> **When do I use for loops?**
>   For loops are traditionally used when you have a piece of code which you want to repeat n number of times. As an alternative, there is the WhileLoop, however, while is used when a condition is to be met, or if you want a piece of code to repeat forever, for example -

The `while` loop feels more natural for this task, because the `for` needs an enumerable or a generator.

But if you really want to do it with a `for` loop, I guess you can construct a generator that yields something until `time.time()<endtime`:

```
def there_is_more_time(e)
    while time.time() < e:
        yield True

for i in there_is_more_time(endtime):
    do something
```

But as you see, you are again using `while` behind the scenes.

Perhaps someone can manage to not use the `while` inside the generator, but what's the point of doing so?

Comment: Sure, you could avoid the inner `while` with, say, `for i in repeat(None):`. Which hopefully demonstrates why you're right, that there is no point in doing so…

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Here's an iterator that gives you the time since start over and over until it reaches the end:

```
def time_counter(seconds):
    starttime = time.time()
    while True:
        now = time.time()
        if now > starttime + seconds:
            break
        yield now - starttime

for t in time_counter(20):
    print(t)
    time.sleep(3)
```

When I run this, it outputs:

```
9.5367431640625e-07
3.002220869064331
6.0040669441223145
9.004395961761475
12.006848812103271
15.009617805480957
18.011652946472168
```

If you need some different value, just change the `yield` expression.

If you don't need any value… then you don't need a `for` statement; your existing code is already perfectly readable, and a `for` loop that iterates over and discards some meaningless values is just going to make it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to create a `scheduler` object?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_time(): 
    print "From print_time", time.time()

def print_some_times():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(1, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(2, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(3, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(4, 1, print_time, ())
    s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
    s.run()
    print time.time()
```

Output:

```
1430392956.35
From print_time 1430392957.35
From print_time 1430392958.35
From print_time 1430392959.35
From print_time 1430392960.35
From print_time 1430392961.35
1430392961.35
```